# I want the data to be permanent store in my Android app

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to store data like in Shared Preference or SQLite in my app . So that the data doesn't get deleted when we clear app data . Infact when we clear data of whatsapp we have to register again,it's registration data also get deleted.But I want to store permanently that first registration data.Is there any way for that?

Comment: Store everything at server side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Everything of an app gets cleared when the user either clicks "Clear Data" or uninstalls-and-reinstalls the app.

Comment: Yes you are correct we can't store data , only shared preference is where we can save the login details. But if we clear app data it will be also cleared.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SDCARD to store data on external storage.
Data will be available until sdcard format or delete your custom storage folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BackupManager](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) to store data and restore it, or you can write your own server application to store this data based on device_id, which you can later restore based on device_id

Comment: Yes this can be one of the solution by saving the data in server.